Software Restriction Policies - HASH Algorithm
I have created a specific software restriction GPO for a specific server in my AD, I want to limit access to certain applications on the server such as PowerShell.
I have used the HASH method to try to achieve the purpose, but it seems that the GPO is correctly applied to the machine but no effect arises. But if I add that policy local on the server everything works correctly.
I have been able to observe that the hashes of powershell.exe are different on my domain controller and on my server, I have carried out that check in this way:

Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5 powershell.exe

So I have identified the fault, I don't know what algorithm is used to calculate the hash of the GPO but with MD5 they are completely different, so the GPO that I make on my DC is not valid for the server, since they are different hashes.
How could I calculate the specific hash for my GPO? What would be the way to do that?

Compare output of $PSVersionTable on DC and on affected server

The output is the same, I also tried it with CMD and other applications without result.

I found this solution, when you specify the new rule and specify the file on which you want to create it. Enter the machine in question with the UNC path, that is, \mymachine\c$ and you can specify the path, the policy was applied correctly.
If anyone has a better idea, please tell me.

Using AppLocker. much better and modern
